# SUM on a bridge table value

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:
**Assets** - things we monitor for customers
**Trouble_tickets**-  Instances of trouble tickets
**parts**- all parts that could be used to fix a trouble ticket
**trouble_ticket_parts**- a bridge table with ticket_id, part_id and qty of part used.  A ticket can have many parts used so it can have many part_id's.

My query is as follows:

```
select a.name, tt.id, sum(if(trouble_ticket_parts.id = 44, parts.qty,0)) as `qty`
    from trouble_tickets tt, trouble_ticket_parts ttp, parts p
    where tt.id = ttp.ticket_id
    and ttp.parts_id = p.id
    and a.id = tt.asset_id
group by a.name asc;
```

My problem is if a ticket was closed with 1 part X and 1 part y it will show a qty of 2.  I am only interested in part x.  So the question is how to get the qty of part x replaced across an inventory of trouble tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.name, tt.id, sum(if(trouble_ticket_parts.id = 44, parts.qty,0)) as `qty`, p.id as partid
    from trouble_tickets tt, trouble_ticket_parts ttp, parts p
    where tt.id = ttp.ticket_id
    and ttp.parts_id = p.id
    and a.id = tt.asset_id
group by
    a.name asc, p.id
;
```

or

```
select a.name, tt.id, sum(if(trouble_ticket_parts.id = 44, parts.qty,0)) as `qty`
    from trouble_tickets tt, trouble_ticket_parts ttp, parts p
    where tt.id = ttp.ticket_id
    and ttp.parts_id = p.id
    and a.id = tt.asset_id
    and p.id = <part-id of x>
group by a.name asc;
```

Comment: Your first query is identical to what I am doing with the exception of adding the part id to the group by.  So it does not improve my results.  I do not understand this :"and p.id = <part-id of x>" part of the second query, could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Adding the part-id to the group by statement will output the sums for each part separated, not one for all - so with 1 part x and 1 part y you get 2 lines, one with part x and 1 piece, the other with part y and one piece. The second query is, if you want ONLY the number for part x: instead of `<part-id of x>` put in the part-id of x, and you will get only one line, with the count for x (1)

Comment: I have another version of the query where I am doing what you have mentioned in the second query.  I still get the same results.  Since the ticket_id is in the bridge table twice it is counting them both.

Comment: Attention! I use p.id - the part-id field from the parts table (which is the same as the part_id field from the bridge table), not the ticket_id. I tested the query in my answer and it works as expected.

Comment: I discovered the problem.  The original query I posted was merely a partial query as I am joining several other tables for additional information. I eliminated those other joins one by one until I got the results I needed. Eugen you are correct your query is accurate!